# Printing Active Report 3 reports in Active Report 6

Tags: c#, .net, activereports

I'm currently trying to upgrade old AR3 reports to AR6 since AR3 does not work on 64-bit environments. While upgrading all reports (there are about 1000) I'd love it if I could still run the AR3 reports in AR6. I've done some tests and it works, but the results vary, a lot of problems with margins etc..

The [documentation](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/arUpgradingPreviousVersions.html) says:

```
 The Windows Forms Viewer control can still display RDF files, which are static copies of reports with data from the time at which they were saved, from older versions of ActiveReports. In most cases, the WebViewer can also display many of these files, although certain reports may not display correctly.
```

"*although certain reports may not display correctly*" - this is probably the problem.

I'm just throwing out this question here; is there any way to fix these problems or am I totally screwed?

Answer (score 0):

The reports from v3 will run just fine in v6 or later versions.  Can you send us one of the reports that is giving you margin problems (that is most probably related to printer).  Are your reports set to use custom printer (u should have some code in the reports that does that) or are runnning against the default printer on the machine?

what other problems are you facing?  Please send us the reports on activereports.support@grapecity.com or post it here http://arhelp.grapecity.com/groups/forum/reporting/

OOC, why go to v6 and not v9 which is the current release version.